# how to transpose and union all column values

Tags: sql-server, vba

**Table1** has  (15,16,17.20) **Table2** has (19,20,21) My resultant table should be
**Table3** (15,16,17,20,19,20,21).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL`, which will retain duplicate records:

```
SELECT col
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT col
FROM Table2
```

If you want the exact ordering you specified, then this subquery will come in handy:

```
SELECT t.col
FROM
(
    SELECT col, 1 AS rank
    FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col, 2 AS rank
    FROM Table2
) t
ORDER BY t.rank,
         t.col
```